# Electron App Folder Structure

Tags: typescript, electron

I've to develop a project with Electron and Typescript.

For organizational purposes, I created a folder called */src* to hold my code. The idea is to modularize into very specific functions.

When I run electron, it opens a browser window that loads my index.html file.

I'm a little fuzzy with the organization of the code, and calls between main an render process.

In my main.ts file, I have the main process that loads the window. But, where the render process code must be written?

On the other hand, how you can create different views (pages) it the application?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no one correct structure, it depends on your experience and personal opinions, app complexity and so on. You can take a look at existing open source apps, maybe you'll get some ideas. https://github.com/sindresorhus/awesome-electron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electron—just being a runtime, as opposed to a framework—does not have a lot of strong opinions on how you organize your code. I think it makes sense to have `./src` folder to store your code.

As you mentioned, `main.ts` spawns a `BrowserWindow` instance, which loaded `index.html`. In theory, you *could* write all of your JavaScript inside some `<script>` tags in the HTML, but as you might imagine that's not really a long-term game plan.

In Electron, however, you *can* use Node's `require`. This will allow you to do something like this in `index.html`:

```
<script>require('./renderer`)</script>
```

Inside `./renderer.js` (or `.ts` in your particular case), you can begin to to require your small modular files to build up your renderer code.